# How to use result of CROSS APPLY in Full-Text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, cross-apply

I want to use the result of `CROSS APPLY` in full-text search (`FREETEXT` or `CONTAINS`) like this:

```
   SELECT  p.Id ,
            p.Name ,
            p.ShortDescription ,
            p.DisplayOrder ,
            cat.Name AS CategoryName
    FROM    dbo.Product AS p
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                    c.Name ,
                                    c.Description ,
                                    c.Id
                          FROM      dbo.Product_Category_Mapping AS m
                                    LEFT JOIN dbo.Category AS c ON m.CategoryId = c.Id
                          WHERE     m.ProductId = p.Id
                                    AND c.Published = 1
                                    AND c.Deleted = 0
                        ) AS cat
    WHERE   p.Published = 1
            AND p.Deleted = 0
            AND ( CONTAINS ( p.NAME, @search )
                  OR CONTAINS ( p.FullDescription, @search )
                  OR CONTAINS ( cat.NAME, @search )
                );
```

My problem is ==>  `OR CONTAINS ( cat.Name, @search )`. 
The error returned by SQL Server is:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'Name' because
>   it is not full-text indexed.

It seems the result of `CROSS APPLY` is a table and this table is not full-text indexed. How can I apply the full-text index search condition to the result of the `CROSS APPLY` above?

Comment: SQL server allows you to use CONTAINS only  when table  is full-text indexed, you can do it by wizard by right clicking on table. Or you may want to use like operator instead

Comment: both of tables (product,category) enabled for full-text search

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  p.Id ,
            p.Name ,
            p.ShortDescription ,
            p.DisplayOrder ,
            cat.Name AS CategoryName
    FROM    dbo.Product AS p
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                    c.Name ,
                                    c.Description ,
                                    c.Id
                          FROM      dbo.Product_Category_Mapping AS m
                                    LEFT JOIN dbo.Category AS c ON m.CategoryId = c.Id
                          WHERE     m.ProductId = p.Id
                                    AND c.Published = 1
                                    AND c.Deleted = 0
                        ) AS cat
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Category cat2 ON cat2.Id = cat.Id
    WHERE   p.Published = 1
            AND p.Deleted = 0
            AND ( CONTAINS ( p.NAME, @search )
                  OR CONTAINS ( p.FullDescription, @search )
                  OR CONTAINS ( cat2.NAME, @search )
                );
```

Note, I have re-joined `dbo.Category` on main level and have changed `CONTAINS` predicate to reference `cat2.NAME` instead of `cat.Name`. `cat` is the `CROSS JOIN` alias which indeed is not under full text-index, but the main `dbo.Category` table aliased under cat2 IS under full-text index, so you can use its column `NAME` with `CONTAINS`.

Also, I think it would be better if you re-write your query and move the `CONTAINS` checks inside the `CROSS JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT  p.Id ,
            p.Name ,
            p.ShortDescription ,
            p.DisplayOrder ,
            cat.Name AS CategoryName
    FROM    dbo.Product AS p
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1
                    c.Name ,
                    c.Description ,
                    c.Id,
                    (CASE WHEN CONTAINS(cat.NAME, @search) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as IsCategoryMatching
                FROM      dbo.Product_Category_Mapping AS m
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Category AS c ON m.CategoryId = c.Id
                WHERE m.ProductId = p.Id
                      AND c.Published = 1
                      AND c.Deleted = 0
            ) AS cat    
    WHERE   p.Published = 1
            AND p.Deleted = 0
            AND ( CONTAINS ( p.NAME, @search )
                  OR CONTAINS ( p.FullDescription, @search )
                  OR cat.IsCategoryMatching=1
                );
```

HTH